# laravel eloquent create using sql (server) functions

Tags: sql-server, laravel, function, eloquent, create-table

Does anybody knows how to use sql server functions in eloquent create?

**For Example:**

> datediff(hour,otherdbField,$request->field2),

or other, like

> hashbytes('SHA1',$request->fieldhashcode)

or any others?

Could give an example, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use them in `whereRaw & selectRaw` clauses

Comment: but in create? the purpose is to insert into. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Why would you not do this either before, or inside your model?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry for my little knowledge of Laravel. But where in the model and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to use `DATEDIFF` or `DATE_FORMAT` functions when inserting data into DB, why don't you format your date using `PHP` before inserting data? you can format it using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

And as [reffered here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/datediff/), `DATEDIFF` takes two arguments, not three(as you have provided), but when inserting data, if you want to use SQL functions you can use something like this:

```
\DB::insert("insert into users (name, created_at) values (SHA1(?), DATE_FORMAT(?, '%Y-%m-%e'))", [$request->name, \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but DATEDIFF uses 3 arguments: First is the frequency needed (year, month, day, hour, min, etc), and the two others are the dates, at least in SQL Server. But, any way, thanks for your tip using DB::insert was very, very useful. The kind of business here needs lots of SQL Functions made on DB. This is why I need it. In this case however,  I just used datediff as an example.

Comment: OK, got it!! You were in SQL SERVER.